# Get the option that was selected - Webmatrix

Tags: razor, webmatrix

I have a form that have a dropdown box, then you have a list that have all the id's that have been inserted and you can edit those id's, my question is. How can i get the option that was selected when the form was submited ?

This is the dropdown on the form that was submited

```
<select name="nivelSeveridade">
                                     <option disabled>-- Selecionar Nível Severidade --</option>
                                     <option>Alerta CC4</option>
                                     <option>Alerta CC3</option>
                                     <option>Alerta CC2</option>
                                     <option>Alerta CC1</option>
</select>
```

This is what i've tried on the edit page:

```
<select name="nivelSeveridade">
                                     <option disabled>-- Selecionar Nível Severidade --</option>
                                     <option>@row.nivelSeveridade</option>
                                     <option>Alerta CC4</option>
                                     <option>Alerta CC3</option>
                                     <option>Alerta CC2</option>
                                     <option>Alerta CC1</option>
</select>
```

As you can see that duplicates the option that was selected. For example if the option selected was "Alerta CC4" i will have two options with the same name.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "How can i get the option that was selected when the form was submited?". Do you want that the dropdown is newly presented with the before selected option displayed at the first place or that the selected option is simply notified to the user with something like "selected option: xxxx"?

Comment: That the selected option is the "default value". I will try to explain better. On the first time the first option will be "Choose an option", then the user select one of the options and insert to the DB. Then if the user edit the form, the option that he selected will be the first that will be presented instead of the "Choose and option". I don't know if this explanation was clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mark as 'selected' the option of a dropdown list that is the same as a given value, you must compare the given value with the value of any option and set the selected attribute accordingly. You could make a list with all the values of your dropdown or optain it from a db table and use a foreach loop to create your dropdown testing their equality.

In your case you can try something like:

```
@{
    List<string> options = new List<string>();
    options.Add("Alerta CC4");
    options.Add("Alerta CC3");
    options.Add("Alerta CC2");
    options.Add("Alerta CC1");
}

<form method="post">
    <select name="nivelSeveridade">
        <option disabled>-- Selecionar Nível Severidade --</option>
        @foreach(var option in options){
            if(option == row.nivelSeveridade){
                <option selected="selected">@option</option>
            } else {
                <option>@option</option>
            }
        }
    </select>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Actually, Razor v2.0 includes some enhancements as Conditional Attributes, that enable to greatly simplify the test part of the former code. Conditional Attributes are setted as result of a boolean value passed to them and the resulting code could be the following:

```
@{
    List<string> options = new List<string>();
    options.Add("Alerta CC4");
    options.Add("Alerta CC3");
    options.Add("Alerta CC2");
    options.Add("Alerta CC1");
}

<form method="post">
    <select name="nivelSeveridade">
        <option disabled>-- Selecionar Nível Severidade --</option>
        @foreach(var option in options){
            <option selected="@(option == row.nivelSeveridade)">@option</option>
        }
    </select>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Mate, thank you very very much for your answer and  explanation. You actually made a noob like me understand it very easily. Thanks !

Comment: i have tested and it's working like a charm. I have just one more question. One of dropdown lists are "feeded" from a DB and i got an error when i tried the foreach. This is the error

Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord' and 'string'

Don i have to change the var to something else so he can compare the values ?

Comment: @Nibbler It looks like you haven't specified the field name that you want to use as value in your dropdown list. In your [former question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829375/cascadingdropdowns-webmatrix) there are a lot of examples of dropdown populated with data from a db. If this doesn't help, maybe you could make another question posting your code.